# Mongodb referencia

Tags: mongodb

Pretendo fazer um Website.
Ira ter duas collections
"listmangas", onde ira ter o nome de vários mangas.
"genero", onde terá os generos do tipo "Ação,Comedia"

No website irá ter formulario para inserir o nome do anime e checkbox para selecionar o genero.

Queria entender como fazer isso no mongodb para depois entender como fazer no website.

Inserir "genero"

```
db.genero.insert({genero:"Comedia"})
db.genero.insert({genero:"Ação"})
```

Inserir nome no "listmangas"

```
db.listmangas.insert({nome:"toriko"})
```

Como referenciar genero:"Ação" no nome:"toriko" ?

Como procurar depois o nome Toriko da listmangas e aparece o genero:"Ação"?

Se ficou meio bagunçado, tento melhorar essa pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do que eu sei, um documento em mongo assume um modelo não relacional e é definido por um conjunto de par de chave - valor. Pelo que para que esse cenário seja possível, você deveria adicionar ao mesmo tempo:

```
db.listmangas.insert({nome:"toriko", genero:"acção "})
```

Em relação à segunda parte da pergunta, tem aqui um bom [exemplo](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) em como fazer a query.

Comment: perfeito,
Fiquei horas pensando em como fazer isso.
Muito obrigado,

Comment: Ora essa Braian, boa sorte!